# Is it possible to open a users local file for read using HTML5?

Tags: html, html5-filesystem

I have a path to a file on the users local system. When the user clicks on that path, the file should open so that the user can view it.

I know that there are lots of limitations on this since we cannot access a users local file due to browser security issues.

Now, I read about HTML5 and it's FileReader API, but all the code examples I see online select and upload the file, and I'm not very clear about whether it is possible to do what i want with it.

Maybe I haven't looked at the right places yet, but anybody know about this?

Comment: For security reasons cannot access arbitrary files from the user's system.

Comment: I agree, and I've read this everywhere online. However, the File API does provide the ability to read files from the users local system, right? Or is there any limitation on this? @Diodeus

Comment: You can view a local file. Look at [mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/DOM/FileReader) for example of local image preview before upload. Of course, you can do this not only with images. For example, use `readAsText` method for reading text from a local file, so you can display it in your page.

Comment: @Stan So, I take it that you can read text or images and then write them again so the user can view the file. However, what about .xlsx, .docx and .pdf files? Is there any way we can open these files for the user?

Comment: No, I mean you read files and display their contents in the page. As for file writing, it's not possible via FileReader and may require tweeking browsers security settings (which is browser specific and even may not exist in some browsers; for example, for FF you need to escalate privileges by `netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege('UniversalXPConnect')`). I suppose, specific file formats can be viewed by embedded objects (powered by installed NPAPI plugins), which support corresponding file type. But there is no universal solution.